# Creating list syntax error

Tags: python-2.7, list, syntax-error

I don't understand why I have a syntax error on this. I'm learning python and currently very newbie, can anyone help me with this? Big Thanks

Comment: On what? Where is the code?

Comment: Include both your code sample and the error received.